# Navigation chain expired issue during oauth code flow on android using chrome fails to activate android app link

Tags: android, google-chrome, oauth, capacitor

We have a capacitor app running on android, from which we start an oAuth code flow.
This will activate chrome in which the authentication should happen. This is a "complex" flow in which you can select multiple options for authentication (itsme,username password).
When I select itsme and itsme app is not installed, another redirection happens to itsme.
If this takes too long (more than 15 seconds), chrome will decide at the end of the oauth code flow not to activate our android app via app linking (which is correctly validated).

Via logcat I see the following:
2023-10-04 11:06:12.362 17316-17316 cr_UrlHandler           com.android.chrome                   I  **Navigation chain expired (a page waited more than 15000 seconds to redirect).**
2023-10-04 11:06:12.363 17316-17316 cr_UrlHandler           com.android.chrome                   I  shouldOverrideUrlLoading result: NO_OVERRIDE

and I would like to see:
shouldOverrideUrlLoading result: OVERRIDE_WITH_EXTERNAL_INTENT

(this would mean chrome would use app linking)

Is someone familiar with this issue: "Navigation chain expired", what are the rules?
How can we avoid this.

PS: a user will have normally installed itsme as an app on the phone, so probably then the issue does not trigger. But we have other oauth code flows that can also trigger the problem, e.g. registering a FIDO key.